# Flurry - Flurry sample app keep replace userid in user journey

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I try to understand flurry by creating sample project and add new API Key to FlurryAnalyticsSampleApp-Android with no custom any parameter. I generated event from several devices. Once data logged to user journey menu it keep replace userid 1 instead of add new userid.

Comment: Is this the user ID logged with setUserID? If so, if you manually set it to a value, and do not change it, it will show the same for all devices. User IDs are not device-dependent. Have you set it up to where it should be logging a different ID for each device?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I also put FlurryAgent.setUserId(uniqueid) to my project and set different uniqueID to multiple devices . but it still show the same result.